# vimeo-api remove part of JSON response

Tags: json, api, vimeo, vimeo-api

Is possible (sending a specific parameter in request) remove part of JSON response?

Like the Youtube API v3 part parameter: The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more video resource properties that the API response will include.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vimeo API supports a fields whitelist, so instead of saying "exclude this", you include a list of everything you want.

There is more documentation here: https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec#json-filter

But the idea is you add the parameter `fields`, and a comma separated list of fields. Nested data should be broken up with periods. So the following representation

```
{
    "name": "dashron",
    "websites": [{
        "name": "facebook"
    },{
        "name": "twitter"
    }],
    "metadata": {
        "albums": {
            "uri": "...",
            "options": "...",
            "total": "..."
    }
}
```

Is the result of an API call with the following fields parameter
`fields=name,websites.name,metadata.albums`